# Pandas: load flattened list into multiple columns (based on separating line)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file with the exact content:

```
COLUMN 1 HEADER
col 1 data line 1
col 1 data line 2
col 1 data line 3
col 1 data line n
COLUMN 2 HEADER
col 2 data line 1
col 2 data line 2
col 2 data line 3
col 2 data line n
COLUMN 3 HEADER
col 3 data line 1
col 3 data line 2
col 3 data line 3
col 3 data line n
```

How can I use Python to load it into a pandas dataframe df with multiple columns, so that

```
print(df)
```

returns

```
     COLUMN 1 HEADER    COLUMN 2 HEADER    COLUMN 3 HEADER
0  col 1 data line 1  col 2 data line 1  col 3 data line 1
1  col 1 data line 2  col 2 data line 2  col 3 data line 2
2  col 1 data line 3  col 2 data line 3  col 3 data line 3
3  col 1 data line n  col 2 data line n  col 3 data line n
```

?

Comment: Need more concrete input with expected output.

Comment: The input is literally a text (.txt) file with the exact lines, how can I clear that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I solved it for me, but I'm wondering if there are easier and less verbose solutions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

txtlines = open(path+"test.txt").readlines()

# remove the line break characters
txtlines = [l.split("\n")[0] for l in txtlines]

# separate the lines based on header
list_of_lists = []
headers = []
for l in txtlines:
    if "COLUMN" in l:
        headers.append(l)
        list_of_lists.append([])
    else:
        list_of_lists[-1].append(l)

# load the lists
df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(list_of_lists), columns=headers)
```

Then I can index the columns:

```
df["COLUMN 1 HEADER"]
```

which returns

```
0    col 1 data line 1
1    col 1 data line 2
2    col 1 data line 3
3    col 1 data line n
```

Comment: To me this returns the same as 'pd.read_csv('example.txt',sep=' ',skipfooter=10)' - what difference do you notice?

Comment: Sorry, I added the output to the answer. Hopefully makes it more clear. 'pd.read_csv('example.txt',sep=' ',skipfooter=10)' does not let me index 'df["COLUMN 1 HEADER"]' because the delimiter (sep=' ') separated the words of the column name

Comment: @Nico Autia have you found any compact solutions to this, if yes, please update it for the rest of us.

Answer (score 0):

You can do use [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), if you save your input to a text file, ie `example.txt`:

```
pd.read_csv('example.txt',sep=' ')
```

This will return a [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Or, if want to keep all information, without headers within the file:

```
pd.read_csv('example.txt',sep=' ',skiprows=[5,10])
```

This will return:

```
        COLUMN  1   HEADER
col 1   data    line    1
    1   data    line    2
    1   data    line    3
    1   data    line    n
    2   data    line    1
    2   data    line    2
    2   data    line    3
    2   data    line    n
    3   data    line    1
    3   data    line    2
    3   data    line    3
    3   data    line    n
```

If you are only interested in the first part of the file as shown in the question, you can use `pd.read_csv('example.txt',sep=' ',skipfooter=10)`. Or just simply delete the part of the file you don't need before reading it in.

Comment: This doesn't solve it for me. I'd need to keep all information, but it should be rearranged in columns. I'm a bit confused how to state the question more clearly (since I think it is rather basic problem).

Comment: Edited my answer, hope this is better now. The thing I find confusing about the original post is that the 4 lines which you want to return do not preserve all information, but you want to - if this answer is still not sufficient, would you try to make that part clearer for me?

Comment: Edited the desired output in the question, hopefully it is more clear now.